# What is the logic behind the output of console.log('\x') where x is an arbitrary number?

Tags: javascript, node.js

What is the logic behind the output of the following examples:

```js
console.log('\272') // -> º

console.log('\364') // -> ô
```

As far as I know, `\` is an escape character in javascript which means it tries to escape the following character but in the first example it is not equal to ASCII code of 72 which is character `H`.

Comment: Where do you see a `72`? You've written `272`. In any case, https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes#octal, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String, etc.

Comment: [mdn - String: Escape notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation) `[...]\XXX an octal Latin-1 character.[...]`

Comment: @AmirJ What do you mean "after escaping the first `2`"? That's not how JS string escaping works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because of the octal encoding.

> Any character with a character code lower than 256 (i.e. any character
>   in the extended ASCII range) can be escaped using its octal-encoded
>   character code, prefixed with . (Note that this is the same range of
>   characters that can be escaped through hexadecimal escapes.)
>
> To use the same example, the copyright symbol ('©') has character code
>   169, which gives 251 in octal notation, so you could write it as
>   '\251'.

You can take a look to this explanation, quite illustrative: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes

Comment: I would add the mdn reference as a resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation

Comment: @briosheje — There's nothing official about MDN. It's a wiki that anyone can edit. (albeit one of generally very high quality). https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/ is the official reference.

Comment: @Quentin you're right, indeed. It's just that MDN is (usually, as far as my experience could tell me) a pretty solid source with high quality content. I wouldn't directly link the ecmascript international reference due to the complexity of it, but still, you're absolutely right. Edited the above comment to actually ask to link the MDN reference, removing "official" from it :P. The **official** reference, if I'm not wrong (correct me if I am) is therefore here: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-additional-syntax-string-literals (_LegacyOctalEscapeSequence_)

Comment: MDM might not be official for the language itself but it is official for browser implementations. https://www.w3.org/blog/2017/10/w3c-to-work-with-mdn-on-web-platform-documentation/

Comment: "Any character in the extended ASCII range" is misleading. \XXX (octal) and \xXX (hex) are for only ISO 8859-1.

Answer (score 1):

They are octal values.

You can find all of them [here](http://www.ascii-code.net/)

However, using octal values are [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Deprecated_octal#Octal_escape_sequences). Using them in strict mode will throw you SyntaxError.

I'll suggest you to use Hexadecimal code instead which you can find in the provided link:

For octal value 272, the hexadecimal value is BA. So, you'll use it prefixed by small letter `x` - denoted as hex value.

```
console.log('\xBA') // -> º
```

Comment: All the octal values?! That list must be yuuuge!